# Keeping a checkbox checked with local storage but also filter a list on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, filtering, angular-local-storage

Alright, this is/was a 2 part question, I originally posted this function:

```
$(function () {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("filter-by");

    if (data !== null) {
        $("input[name='filters']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }


});



$("input[name='filters']").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("filter-by", $(this).val());
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("filters");
    }

});
```

As the start to my re-checking a checkbox after load using local storage. After some trial and error someone was able to help me write this new function:

```
$("input[name='filters']").click(function () {
  var items = localStorage.getItem("filter-by") || [];
  var data = this.data('filter-by');

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    items.push(data);
  } else if (items.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
    items.splice(items.indexOf(data), 1);
  }

  if (items.length > 0) {
    localStorage.setItem("filter-by", items);
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem("filter-by");
  }
});


$(function () {
  var items = localStorage.getItem("filter-by") || [];

  $("input[name='filters']").each(function(index, input) {
    var data = $(input).data('filter-by');
    if (items.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
      $(input).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  });
});
```

With this function, I'm able to store which checkboxes were checked, but the list does not filter. How can I go about making the list filter on refresh as well, using either of my functions?

I am using an input that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters" data-filter-by="Brand A" ng-click="includeBrand('Brand A')" />Brand A
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have to trigger the click event or you need to call includeBrand(filterString) function for each of the checked items on page load.

Comment: How would I go about triggering the click event?

Comment: Well, it a basic Jquery statement. For your loop, this should work: $(input).trigger('click');

Comment: onClick()? I am not that great in JS/jQuery.

Comment: Why do I need a click event? Onload, after visiting, it saves the checkboxes as clicked/checked, but it doesn't save the filtered list?

Comment: Setting the state of checkbox to 'checked' programmatically, doesn't trigger click automatically. And you are filtering the data on ng-click.

Comment: Ah, so I just need to add the trigger onto where I check the input?
`$(input).trigger('click').attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: You can just trigger the 'click'. It would also change the state to 'checked'. Setting the attribute again is unnecessary in my view.